# Update Navigation Properties

Tags: entity-framework

I am a newbie to Entity framework and I was confused when i want to update an existing Entity with Navigation Property.
Here is an Model class I am using.

```
public class Institution
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string PreferURL { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EntitlementEntity> Entitlement{ get; set; }
}
```

I did an MVC HttpPost back in the edit action with auto deserialization from SCOTT HANSELMAN(http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx).

Everything works fine if I ignore Navigation Properties`ICollection<EntitlementEntity> Entitlement` in the form; once included, an exception throw.

```
{"An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager.
 The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key."}
```

I finally got it work as below.
https://gist.github.com/pwang2/8363266

What i am reluctant to do is we already have all the relations in the original Institution Entity with Navigation Property, but here I have to set the institution relation for every Entitlement Entity again.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to update the institution entity as well as its Navigation Properties at the same time.
2. If not, what's the best practice if I want a more concentrate UI result to allow update both the institutional information and its entitlement at the same time?

Comment: Why does Entity Framework Reinsert Existing Objects into My Database? msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx

Comment: Thank Colin for the link from Julie Lerman. As the start, i only took the benefit of the EF regardless states of object/entity.